# Flow into view (don't know the technical term)

Tags: css

I don't know what this is called, but I've seen it on a few websites where when a div scrolls into view it flows to the top hiding the previous block (well scrolling out of view). It like a slideshow but vertically and shows the content. It's kinda like a normal scrolling web page but brings segments into view.

Does this make sense??

Does anyone know what this is called so I can Google how to do it in `css` or `jQuery`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's called Parallax.

Comment: parallax effect. You can use `Adobe Muse` to create professional parallax effects.

Comment: fullpage scrolling. See https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullpage.js and/or https://github.com/Viewdesic/viewScroller.js

Comment: This doesn't sound like Parallax at all. I think what you're looking for goes by "scroll hijacking" and is often frowned upon among UI/UX experts. Here's an example: https://codyhouse.co/demo/page-scroll-effects/index.html

Comment: Sounds like lazily loading elements using CSS animations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question you are searching for sticky position. You can see how to do it here: https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/